# How does Gmail hide their Subject line overflow?

Tags: css, gmail

How does Gmail hide/clip/truncate their Subject line overflow?

It's not just as simple overflow:hidden because I've tried all that.  It must be something elaborate.

The width of the table is 100% and NOT fixed-width and the table-layout is NOT "fixed" so the solution can't use that either.  Only one column stretches and the rest are fixed-width.  I've tried everything I could find on the web they all cheat with table-layout="fixed".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh they put a div in the cell with `overflow: hidden;`, and then the subject in that.

I've done it myself in a site; a snippet:

html:

```
<td class="vtc"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div></td>
```

css:

```
.vtc {
    width: 144px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

.vtc div {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Ahh - the key was the class on the table cell and a div inside the cell around the content. thanks!

Comment: The width needed to be removed from the .vtc and the key is to make sure the div height is set so that there's only room for one line of text.  Otherwise, the text will wrap instead.

Comment: Thanks Quiche, I have implemented your solution. I would like to see a more complete example with ellipsis on truncated lines, etc...

Comment: Here you go Neil: http://jsfiddle.net/U8KRK/ I think this is actually much cleaner than the accepted answer too.